# C# max() not returning the natural highest Value

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary of `<string, Point>` and the keys in this dictionary look like this:

- char_1_1
- char_1_2
- ...
- char_1_9
- char_1_10

Now I am using the following statement to receive the heighest Value of the keys:

```
pointsWhichBelongTogether.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains(searchStringPattern[0] + "_" + searchStringPattern[1] + "_")).OrderBy(x => x, new NaturalStringComparer()).Max()
```

Which uses the following Compare-Class:

```
public class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        private static readonly Regex _re = new Regex(@"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            x = x.ToLower();
            y = y.ToLower();
            if (string.Compare(x, 0, y, 0, Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length)) == 0)
            {
                if (x.Length == y.Length) return 0;
                return x.Length < y.Length ? -1 : 1;
            }
            var a = _re.Split(x);
            var b = _re.Split(y);
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                int r = PartCompare(a[i], b[i]);
                if (r != 0) return r;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        private static int PartCompare(string x, string y)
        {
            int a, b;
            if (int.TryParse(x, out a) && int.TryParse(y, out b))
                return a.CompareTo(b);
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
```

So I assume that the List is natural sorted and the Max-Functions just gets the highest value. But the `max()` returns `char_1_9` as the highest value. Does this max()-function a re-sort?

Comment: since you are sotring strings (and not numbers), `char_1_9` is actually considered larger than `char_1_10`.

Comment: Ordering a collection before calling `Max()` does what exactly? You're simply calling `IEnumerable<string>.Max()`.

Comment: But I did a natural Sort before?

Comment: If you just need to get maximum value, you don't need to order all of the elements. Iterate through all of them and remember the current maximum, it's much more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

- Take the `Last` from the sorted list or
- Order descending and take the first

Right now you sort using your comparer, but `Max` does not use the comparer but the default comparer to find the maximum.

```
pointsWhichBelongTogether.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains(searchStringPattern[0] + "_" + searchStringPattern[1] + "_"))
    .OrderBy(x => x, new NaturalStringComparer()).Last();
```

or

```
pointsWhichBelongTogether.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains(searchStringPattern[0] + "_" + searchStringPattern[1] + "_"))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x, new NaturalStringComparer()).First();
```

---

Edit: in a previous version I suggested to pass the comparer to `Max`, but it seems there is no overload that takes a comparer, only a selector.

Comment: @Snickbrack it was a copy and paste error, I was still looking for a `Max` overload that takes a comparer and forgot to remove that unfinished line.

Answer (score 1):

The `string` type already implements `IComparable<string>` so `Max()` uses this implementation regardless of any previous sorting. I would order your values descending and take the first value:

```
var max = pointsWhichBelongTogether.Keys
    .Where(key => key.Contains(searchStringPattern[0] + "_" + searchStringPattern[1] + "_"))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x, new NaturalStringComparer())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```